# Retrograde Watches

Tags: terminology, relative-motion, time

I am not a physicist and not familiar with physics that much.I have a watch which has `Retrograde motion`. I have read about what is `Retrograde`. But the thing i can't understand is what is the purpose of this module in `wrist watches` and how can we take help from it.

Comment: The purpose is to extract substantial amounts of money from "watch collectors" for mechanically completely trivial complications. It seems to work quite well for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In watchmaker lingo, a "retrograde" watch is a watch that has a hand on it (usually to tell you the day or date) that will advance along and then at the end of its "cycle" will snap backwards to its original position -- rather than loop around the way the hour, minute, and second hands do.

This has nothing to do with the "retrograde motion" discussed in physics/astronomy where planets appear to move backward in the sky (which you can find out more about in the corresponding wikipedia article about it if you like).

Although I don't think that watchmakers are really trying to fool or deceive anyone, I suspect that they rather proudly put this term on the watch and/or packaging because it sounds so sophisticated and elegant.

Comment: Footnote: The English word *retrograde* is derived from Latin words which mean *walk backwards*. It is applied in many different subject areas, often for things that mostly move in one direction but which occasionally reverse direction for a relatively short time.  Mundane uses of a word found in science often have no connection to the use in science. Or at best a very tenuous and potentially misleading connection. E.g. Seiko's "atomic" watches, "perpetual" watches.